# How to insert record from one table into another table using group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Basically i want to insert specific columns from A table into B table using group by clause. A table is parent child relation table and i want to move that records to two table one for parent records and another for detail record. One to Many relations. For this i need to use group by clause to insert specific columns which i need in A table. Here is my attempt.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_ItemReturnMaster (FromTo_Type_Id, From_Id, To_Id, ReturnedDate, 
                                  StatusId, UserId, Reason, DateUpdated, PharmaReturnID)
    SELECT 
        FromTo_TypeId, From_Id, To_Id, ReturnDate,
        StatusId, UserId, Reason, DateUpdated, PharmaReturnID
    FROM 
        tbl_InternalItemReturns 
    GROUP BY 
        ReturnBatchID, From_Id
```

I use following query to fetch records which i really need using group by here is the query.

```
select 
    ReturnBatchID, From_Id 
from 
    tbl_InternalItemReturns 
group by 
    ReturnBatchID, From_Id
```

When I run the first query, I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
>   Column 'tbl_InternalItemReturns.FromTo_TypeId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But the problem is that I don't want to use all the columns in group by clause it return me unnecessary records and I don't want to insert that records in B table.

Comment: The error is quite clear: if you use `group by` you can select only the columns specified in the `group by` and aggregated columns.

Comment: Why do you even have a `GROUP BY` - since you don't have **any** aggregation functions (like `SUM`, `COUNT`) this is utterly useless....

Comment: Because when i don't use group clause it gives me unwanted records which i don't want to insert into table B. By using group i get desire record which i actually need to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you really want a window function, such as:

```
SELECT FromTo_TypeId, From_Id, To_Id, ReturnDate,
       StatusId, UserId, Reason, DateUpdated, PharmaReturnID
FROM (SELECT iir.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  ReturnBatchID, From_Id ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tbl_InternalItemReturns iir
     ) iir
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per `ReturnBatchID`/`From_Id` pair.  The specific row is the most recently updated one.